# How to return multipart content mime in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mime

I am trying to create an IActionResult which returns a multipart content mime message (https://support.fastspring.com/hc/en-us/articles/207436226-MIME-1-0-License-Output-Format)

I researched online but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this.

How can I create such a message and return it as an IActionResult?

Comment: My suggestion, use a JSON response instead.

Comment: Sorry that's not possible in my case

Comment: There is no built support for that, that's why I suggested JSON. You have to develop your own mechanism.